# Clipping with Voronoi polygon using QGIS

Tags: qgis, network, road, polyline-creation, voronoi-thiessen

I'm trying to clip a road network (polyline) with Voronoi polygons. The polyline don't clip but I don't know why. I try to separate my road network according to geographical points collected in the field. This seems to be the only method I know of to separate road sections based on the value of a point.

Comment: Which are the tools you are using? Do you get any errors?

Comment: I use the clip tools as well as the voronoi polygons present in the vector geoprocessing tools. I have no error message. Looks like the voronoi polygons used do not act as a cookie cutter to cut polylines.

Comment: It should work...

Comment: You could try Intersect. Then delete the added fields you dont want